# AWS Lambda can't delete Amazon S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda function, which processes a file uploaded to the first bucket, then saves it to the second bucket and then deletes the input file.

The problem is that when I'm trying to delete the file I'm getting

```js
{
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "code": "AccessDenied",
  "time": "2015-02-09T22:08:45.926Z",
  "statusCode": 403,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 30
}
```

The code snippet, which tries to delete the file is

```js
s3.deleteObject({
    Bucket: inputBucket,
    Key: inputKey
}, function(a, b) {
    if (a) {
        console.error("Error on delete");
        console.error(a);
    } else {
        console.log("Deleted successfully");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

The possible reason why lambda wasn't able to delete the file ( S3 object ) could be due to the Lambda's Execution Role.

**Steps to solve this**

1. Navigate to the IAM in AWS Management Console
2. Look up for the IAM Role used ( or created ) for the lambda ( if it is default it would be lambda_exec_role )
3. Go to Attach Role Policy -> Custom Policy and add the below IAM Policy Document

---

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1423535846414",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Or preferably "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::firstbucket/*"

Comment: What is Sid? where can I get it?

Comment: Statement id to categorize / identify each IAM statement. More like a friendly name "for-s3-access-for-app1"

Answer (score 1):

Go to `IAM -> Roles -> <assigned-role-name> -> Permissions -> <policy-name>`

Make sure your policy has the following:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }

    ]
}
```

Note: `arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>` is for accessing `my-bucket` whereas
`arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*` is for accessing all objects under `my-bucket`. They are similar but not the same. They need to be both present to ensure lambda has full S3 access

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing the first resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with weird characters and spaces within inputKey. Try with a simple name.